# Fatal Error, ArrayObject::offsetGet() must be compatible with that ArrayAccess:offsetGet() with Zend framework 2.3 on Linux Debian 2.6.32-46

Tags: php, zend-framework2, debian, arrayobject

Hi i have problem with ZF2,

when trying to access at public/index from the browser i got this Fatal Error from Server:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Declaration of Zend\\Stdlib\\ArrayObject::offsetGet() must be compatible with that of ArrayAccess::offsetGet() in /var/www/somevirtualhost/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Stdlib/ArrayObject.php on line 23
```

I already update the composer.json from:

```
{
    "name": "zendframework/skeleton-application",
    "description": "Skeleton Application for ZF2",
    "license": "BSD-3-Clause",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "zf2"
    ],
    "homepage": "http://framework.zend.com/",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "zendframework/zendframework": "2.3.*"
    }
}
```

to:

```
{
    "name": "zendframework/skeleton-application",
    "description": "Skeleton Application for ZF2",
    "license": "BSD-3-Clause",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "zf2"
    ],
    "homepage": "http://framework.zend.com/",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "zendframework/zendframework": "2.2.*"
    }
}
```

Also on init_autoloader.php i added this lines:

```
 require $zf2Path . '/Zend/Stdlib/compatibility/autoload.php';
 require $zf2Path . '/Zend/Session/compatibility/autoload.php';
```

and this how init_autoloader looks like:

```
if ($zf2Path) {
    if (isset($loader)) {
        $loader->add('Zend', $zf2Path);
        $loader->add('ZendXml', $zf2Path);
    } else {
        include $zf2Path . '/Zend/Loader/AutoloaderFactory.php';
        Zend\Loader\AutoloaderFactory::factory(array(
            'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
                'autoregister_zf' => true
            )
        ));

        //Fix for PHP 5.3.3
        require $zf2Path . '/Zend/Stdlib/compatibility/autoload.php';
        require $zf2Path . '/Zend/Session/compatibility/autoload.php';
    }
}
```

Besides all the changes mentioned above, i still receive the getting the same error. 
By the way this is my PHP Versión:

```
PHP 5.3.3-7+squeeze19 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Feb 18 2014 13:59:15) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2009 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2010 Zend Technologies
    with Suhosin v0.9.32.1, Copyright (c) 2007-2010, by SektionEins GmbH
```

Comment: There is a closed issue on Github from Feb 2013. It points exactly same situation and seems related with composer autoloading process. https://github.com/zendframework/ZFTool/issues/26

Comment: This is the error you get if you try and run ZF 2.3 on too old a PHP version. After updating `composer.json` to drop it back to 2.2 are you sure you ran `composer update`? Check `Zend\Version\Version.php` to see what version you have.

Comment: as @TimFountain said. Minimum required PHP Version for **2.3.*** is **>=5.3.23**. So either update your PHP Environment of you have to go with ZF 2.2.*

Comment: Problem solved.  @TimFountain, indeed i made a self-updated to the composer, but on Zend\Version\Version.php  the version still the same:   const VERSION = '2.3.1'. What i had to do is to download a latest zendframework again, edit the composer.json to a previous 2.2.* ,and execute the self-update and install options.

Answer (score 1):

I just moved to ZF 2.2 to fix

```
Fatal error: Declaration of Zend\Stdlib\ArrayObject::offsetGet() must be compatible with that of ArrayAccess::offsetGet() in /path/application/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Stdlib/ArrayObject.php on line 22
```

Edit `composer.json` by changing 2.3 to 2.2

```
"zendframework/zendframework": "2.2.*",
```

Then `php composer.phar update`

Answer (score 0):

In doing software archaeology today, I ran into this issue with both "ZF 2.2.x" and "ZF 2.3.x". Taking a shot in the dark with "ZF 2.4.x" managed to resolve the issue.

My project's `composer.json` was modified to use this:

```
(...)
    "zendframework/zendframework": "2.4.*",
(...)
```